# Samsung galaxy S7 cant open camera

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera

I found a bug in my app. the camera intent is not opening only in Samsung s7.
the permission is granted on runtime and i doublechecked that its really granted in the phone.
still i cant open camera to take picture or open picture.
any ideas?

```
  private void takePicture() throws IOException {

    // Create the File where the photo should go
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = AppUtils.createImageFile(AppUtils.ImageType.JPG, AppGlobals.APP_NAME);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AppLog.error(TAG, String.format("Failed to create file for saving the picture - %s",
                e.getMessage()));
    }

    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile == null) {
        throw new IOException(getString(R.string.failed_to_take_picture));
    }

    currentImagePath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();

    AppUtils.takePhotoFromFragment(this, RequestCodes.TAKE_PICTURE, photoFile);
}




    public static File createImageFile(ImageType type, String internalFolder) throws Exception {
    // Create an image file name
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", Locale.US);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    File storageDir;
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(internalFolder)){
        storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    }else{
        storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),
                internalFolder);
    }

    if(!storageDir.exists()){
        if(!storageDir.mkdir()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    File image;

    String imageFileName;
    String imageType;
    if(type == ImageType.PNG){
        imageType = "png";
        imageFileName = timeStamp;
    }else{
        imageType = "jpg";
        imageFileName = timeStamp;
    }

    image = new File(storageDir, String.format("%s.%s", imageFileName, imageType));
    if(image.createNewFile()){
        return image;
    }

    return null;
}





    public static void takePhotoFromFragment(Fragment fragment, int requestCode, File imageFile){
    try {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(fragment.getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
            fragment.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode);
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open camera for taking picture!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error log?

Comment: this is the log when im trying to open the picture i took in the app with other mobiles.

Comment: W/ExifInterface: Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface.
                 java.io.EOFException

Comment: but when im trying to open the camera there are no errors in the log beside the error in the catch block. }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open camera for taking picture!");
    }

Comment: One caveat could be that your **photoFile** cannot be reached by your app or by the Camera app. Check if the Camera opens if you don't `takePictureIntent.putExtra()`.

Comment: Ok, have you ever open the camera preview fragment?  just preview?

Comment: Yep, i removed the takePictureIntent.putExtra() and the camera opened. but why its only in the galaxy s7?

Comment: and the photo i took is not shown in the tumb.